# flowbite injecting css classes in dom next.js 14 hydration error's

Tags: flowbite

I have set up both a navbar and a Tab default on pages and they both cause hydration errors if you reload the page. I have narrowed down the issue to flowbites injecting colors into the DOM that I did not create on the server. I cant figure out if its a setting or something in my programming. I have a Tab Default interactive that I have modified the colors to my liking directly on the tab element:

This is 1 tab, note text-black is the last classname in the tab button:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        //initalize flowbite component
        initFlowbite();
```

```
         <React.Fragment>
        <div className="mb-3  
                        border-b border-slate-200 dark:border-slate-700">
            {/**Start */}
            <ul className="flex flex-wrap
                        font-h2h6 text-lg
                        text-center 
                        border-b
                        text-slate-700  border-slate-200 
                        dark:border-slate-700 dark:text-slate-400"
                id="defaultTab"     
                data-tabs-toggle="#defaultTabContent" 
                role="tablist">

                <li key="0" className="me-2" role="presentation">
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        //remove any query string we are on the start page
                        router.push(pathname, undefined);
                    }}
                    aria-current="page"
                    className="inline-block 
                                px-4 py-2 rounded-t-lg                              
                                hover:text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-200 
                                dark:hover:bg-slate-800 dark:hover:text-slate-300
                                aria-selected:text-black aria-selected:bg-indigo-200
                                text-black" 
                    id="startTab" 
                    data-tabs-target="#start" type="button" 
                    role="tab" aria-controls="start" 
                    aria-selected={activeTab === 0}
                    >&nbsp;Start&nbsp;</button>
                </li>
```

I go to the page and look at the element in google developers tools it presents with extra color elements(below). So if the page is refreshed the server code doesnt match, which I presume is causing the hydration error

Where is All this blue coming from? I am not using blue

```
    <button aria-current="page" 
    class="inline-block px-4 py-2 rounded-t-lg 
    hover:text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-200 
    dark:hover:bg-slate-800 dark:hover:text-slate-300 
    aria-selected:text-black aria-selected:bg-indigo-200 
    text-black 
            //flowbite injected colors
            text-blue-600 
            hover:text-blue-600 
            dark:text-blue-500 
            dark:hover:text-blue-500 
            border-blue-600 
            dark:border-blue-500" 
            //end
    id="startTab" data-tabs-target="#start" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="start" aria-selected="true">&nbsp;Start&nbsp;</button>
```

I wasnt expecting it to inject what I presume are theme colors. I dont see any themes that I can alter and the themeing documentation, I see where you can override themes but I cant find  where the default theme is  to override it. Obviously there is no point in me changing blue-600 to slate-500 in the tailwind.confg. My other thought is why am I including my on colors on the element if they are injected by flowbite? All the examples show the colors on the elements so I am not sure why they are being injected.

I do have both flowbite-react and flowbite installed, not sure if thats the issue.

Comment: Update, I uninstalled flowbite-react the cause was not trying to run the two together. The extra flowbite color classes only seem to be on the first element. I have 4 tabs like the one in the code and it is the only one that is getting the  extra colors. I tried reanaming it and taking out default any where I saw it in tags. Had no effect first element always has extra elements I didnt put there. html has been validated w3.org, just in case.

Comment: I have confirmed its adding tailwind color classes to all the elements. Unless tailwind is adding them for some reason?

Comment: I have fixed the hydration errors on the nav bar where flowbite's was adding data-popper by using nextjs dynamic import //flowbite mods element tree adding elements causing hydration errors
const NavNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('@/app/components/nav/Navsite'), { ssr: false })
I am still concerned with additional tailwind classes overridding the classes that I set in the Tab Default.